# Two overlaping materials on the same X axis

Tags: materials, color

Hu guys. I have two overlapping materials. The roof is entering the house wall so I don't have to tinker around to snap it directly to the wall. Since they are on the same level I want the housing red material to take over as the dominant color. Is that possible if they are on the same level?[image]

Comment: Why not move the roof a little bit inside? It's easier and even more realistic.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) -- your faces are overlapping each other so the renderer can't figure out which one to show.  I'd recommend either moving the face of the porch roof inward a bit so the wall hides it, or shortening the porch roof so it's up against the wall instead of inside it.